# Surcharges Supported for Repeat Transactions?

Tags: opayo

Please would someone confirm whether Sage Pay supports returning the surcharge amount within the response to repeat posts?

I have implemented server integration version 3.  Responses to notification posts provide the surcharge amount.  However, the same information does not seem to be provided within responses to repeat posts.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question in an e-mail to Sage Pay support, and they promptly responded with the following information:

Surcharges can only be used for the following payment types.

•PAYMENT
•AUTHENTICATE
•DEFERRED

You cannot send surcharge XML or have surcharges applied via My Sage Pay for any other payment types.

The surcharge is applied depending on the BIN range check on our servers. Our servers function this way to avoid multiple surcharges being added to customer payments, e.g. a surcharge is added to a deferred payment, then another surcharge being added to the release payment.

Comment: Well that's wrong for a start! There are fields for applying surcharges to REPEAT transactions within MSP!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a further API call to get this information. Sample response below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?><vspaccess>  <errorcode>0000</errorcode>  <timestamp>17/03/2016 11:36:09</timestamp>  <vpstxid>8663ACE6-5B28-6C10-605A-0485BDDA7911</vpstxid>  <vendortxcode>splabs-7038</vendortxcode>  <transactiontype>Repeat</transactiontype>  <txstateid>16</txstateid>  <status>Successfully authorised transaction.</status>  <relatedtransactionid>A0A77ABF-5AD3-F97C-1DCE-5CF8C7D5C2B5</relatedtransactionid>  <relatedamount>0.00</relatedamount>  <description>Repeat</description>  <amount>7.77</amount>  <currency>GBP</currency>  <started>17/03/2016 11:35:24.247</started>  <completed>17/03/2016 11:35:24.830</completed>  <securitykey>64QLFDA8R0</securitykey>  <clientip>151.224.228.103</clientip>  <giftaid>NO</giftaid>  <paymentsystem>VISA</paymentsystem>  <paymentsystemdetails>Credit Card - Sagepay Test Visa, GB</paymentsystemdetails>  <startdate></startdate>  <expirydate>0726</expirydate>  <last4digits>0006</last4digits>  <authprocessor>HSBC</authprocessor>  <merchantnumber>425865224643</merchantnumber>  <accounttype>E</accounttype>  <vpsauthcode>10368857</vpsauthcode>  <bankauthcode>999777</bankauthcode>  <billingfirstnames>Kristian</billingfirstnames>  <billingsurname>Dimitrov</billingsurname>  <billingaddress>Address 1</billingaddress>  <billingcity>Varna</billingcity>  <billingpostcode>W1A 0AX</billingpostcode>  <billingcountry>GB</billingcountry>  <billingphone>01222 555 555</billingphone>  <deliveryfirstnames>Kristian</deliveryfirstnames>  <deliverysurname>Dimitrov</deliverysurname>  <deliveryaddress>Address 1</deliveryaddress>  <deliverycity>Varna</deliverycity>  <deliverypostcode>W1A 0AX</deliverypostcode>  <deliverycountry>GB</deliverycountry>  <deliveryphone>01222 555 555</deliveryphone>  <cardholder>Kristian Dimitrov</cardholder>  <cardfirstnames>Kristian</cardfirstnames>  <cardsurname>Dimitrov</cardsurname>  <cardaddress>Address 1</cardaddress>  <cardcity>Varna</cardcity>  <cardpostcode>W1A 0AX</cardpostcode>  <cardcountry>GB</cardcountry>  <systemused>S</systemused>  <vpsprotocol>3.00</vpsprotocol>  <refunded>NO</refunded>  <repeated>NO</repeated>  <basket></basket>  <applyavscv2>0</applyavscv2>  <apply3dsecure>0</apply3dsecure>  <authattempt>1</authattempt>  <cv2result>NOTPROVIDED</cv2result>  <addressresult>NOTPROVIDED</addressresult>  <postcoderesult>NOTPROVIDED</postcoderesult>  <threedresult>NOTCHECKED</threedresult>  <t3maction>NORESULT</t3maction>  <emailmessage></emailmessage>  <locale>en</locale>  <declinecode>00</declinecode>  <surcharge>0.00</surcharge></vspaccess>
```